# Spring Boot - Mock Interceptors

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-test, springmockito

I'm having an issue while testing Rest request. 
However test is being **intercepted** by one of my interceptors.

In short I want to *mock* interceptors behaviour rather than calling actual implementation.

For simplicity purposes to visualise the issue here is a simply Get request

```
@Controller
public class HiController {

    @ResponseBody
    @GetMapping(value = "/hi", produces = {"application/json"})
    public String hi() {
        return "hi";
    }
}
```

with simple interceptor and config file

```
@Component
public class LoggingInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

    @Override
    public final boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response, final Object handler) {
        System.out.println("Logging token interceptor");
        return true;
    }
}

@Component
public class InterceptorAppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private LoggingInterceptor loggingTokenInterceptor;

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(loggingTokenInterceptor);
    }
}
```

the purpose of test was to call rest endpoint and to mock interceptor

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(HiController.class)
public class HiControllerTest extends MvcTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Mock
    private HiController controller;

    private static final String AUTHENTICATE_USER = "/hi";

    @Test
    public void mandatoryFieldMissing() throws Exception {

        this.mockMvc.perform(get(AUTHENTICATE_USER))
                .andExpect(content().string(containsString("hi")))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public abstract class MvcTest {

    @MockBean
    LoggingInterceptor loggingTokenInterceptor;
}
```

When I run this test ^ `LoggingInterceptor` is still being called.

How can I configure tests to have mock interceptors?

Comment: why not directly have this `@MockBean LoggingInterceptor loggingTokenInterceptor;` in `HiControllerTest`

Comment: yes, I can do this. This not gonna make a difference

Answer (score 0):

You are using `@MockBean`. From the documentation,

> If a bean, compatible with the declared class exists in the context, it replaces it by the mock. If it is not the case, it adds the mock in the context as a bean.

The mocked bean does not have behavior. Realize that by mocking the bean, the onus is on you to define the behavior.

You can either disable mocking the bean(to allow for default behavior)
    `Mockito.doCallRealMethod().when(loggingTokenInterceptor).preHandle(Mockito.any(), Mockito.any(), Mockito.any());`

Or you can define the behavior for the mocked bean yourself.